# Python pygame event - how it works

Tags: events, types, pygame

I started recently learning python pygame and I got stuck already at the beginning.

I have following code here:

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type ==  pygame.QUIT:
              gameExit = True
```

I do not understand how the `for event in pygame.event.get()` works. What kind of loop is that? It does not say how much times it has to loop, there is no range and `event` is just a variable, so can anyone explain how it works?

Furthermore how does event.type work? Again, `event` is just a variable, how does Python recognize that this is an event? I could have named it Pink_Panther or so.

Comment: This work as any generic for loop in Python. Python is a 'for each' loop and will go through all items in a list, tuple, string, range-object, etc. Your loop will go through all elements you receive from `pygame.event.get()`, which could be many events of few events. Each element is an `EventType` and have the attribute `type`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/5110/event-handling/18046/event-loop#t=20170207145554637194) is a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going to https://www.pygame.org/docs/index.html, the home of all official Pygame documentation.

The loop you are asking about works just like a normal Python for loop.  `pygame.event.get()` returns a list (EventList, to be exact, but that doesn't matter right now).  If a for loop is given a list, it iterates through it one element at a time, and puts it into the variable specified: in this case, `event`.  The list that the function returns is full of `pygame.event.Event` or `pygame.event.EventType` objects.  So each loop the earliest unprocessed event is put into the `event` variable, and it loops through the code to handle that event. Here are the steps it takes, compared to a normal for loop:

Pygame event loop:

1. `pygame.event.get()` returns a list with all unprocessed events.
2. For every event in the returned list, copy the event to the variable "event" and execute the following code:
3. *your code here*

Normal for loop:

1. For every value in the list or tuple, copy the value to the variable  and execute the following code:
2. *your code here*

Notice that a common form of a for loop is:

```
for variable in range(stuff):
```

`range()` is actually a function that returns a list!  Open your terminal and type the following:

```
>>> range(5)
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

`pygame.event.get()` returns a list in the same way `range()` returns a list! In Python 3 however, `range()` doesn't return a list but rather a range object. However, the principle is the same.

If you need more clarification, just let me know in the comments.

Comment: Did this answer your question, or do you need more help?